# React & reselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following code in react

**my Reducer**

```
import SHOP_DATA from "./SHOP_DATA";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    
       collections : SHOP_DATA,
}


const shopReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE,action)=>{
    switch (action.type){
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default shopReducer;
```

**my Selector**

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

const selectShop = state=> state.shop;

export const selectCollections = createSelector([selectShop],shop=>shop.collections)
```

**my component**

```
import React from 'react';
import CollectionPreview from '../../../components/collection-preview/collection-preview.component';
import { selectCollections } from '../../../redux/shop/shop.selector';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

const ShopPage =({ collections })=>{
    
        return (
            <div>
                {collections.map(({ id, ...otherProps }) => (
                    <CollectionPreview key={id} {...otherProps} />
                ))}
            </div>
        )
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    collections: selectCollections,
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ShopPage)
```

so the problem is the following
for some reason when I try to log the collections in my component
it renders it twice first the console shows the collections array and it's undefined
can't understand why it is like that.
Important to say I don't have a strict mode
when I try to render the component it says

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

if someone could explain this issue I will appreciate it thanks in advance.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].